# Crashed mint 17.. need to obtain files

Tags: command-line, files, linux-mint

Ok, was noticing that every time I logged into facebook it said for better performance upgrade your browser .. I use google chrome.  For some reason my mint 17 was not allowing me up update like it once did but other things were functioning ok.  I noticed that there were updates sitting there ... so i went updating and my entire linux crashed ... to the point where I could not boot up at all.  Grabbed my boot disk that I had from the beginning and loaded that .. however it is Mint 16 cinnamon .. 32 bit.  Also at some point I managed some how to hit switch user.  So essentially I am on 16 as a secondary user.  I want to just nuke the entire system and start over ... however there were still files on the mint 17 side that crashed .. I want those.  Is there a way .. from this secondary user .. or a way somehow (for someone who is not brilliant with linux) to do something at start up to retrieve the files ... or some how pull them from this secondary user?  I do have all of my passwords so that is not a problem .. I just want to download a newer linux .. get my files .. and then nuke this machine so that it runs ok again.  This mint 16 is driving me nuts.  Thank you.  Please have a good day.

Comment: that's almost unreadable but if i've interpreted it right, you should be able to just mount your old mint 17 filesystem(s), copy your files (e.g. to a usb drive), and then erase the disk before installing a new mint or whatever.

Comment: Being able to salvage files depends on how you reinstalled from the disc, but if you had another disk partition that contained those files you seek to recover, or didn't re-format the root filesystem (if there was only one partition for all of Linux), things go much harder. If you're lucky, you just need to do what @cas said (might possibly require that you switch to a user that allows doing stuff with root privileges). I'm not familiar with Mint so I have to be pretty vague here, sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

Simply boot up your PC or laptop using a linux live DVD/CD of your choice. Use for example the DVD/CD from which you installed your Mint distribution. Then you will be able to boot up a complete desktop environment without relying on the filesystems currently available on your hard drive. From the live image  you should also get access to your hard drive partitions...

**Edit:**

Based on your recent comments I prepared a little walkthrough at [this page](https://dada-hoelz.eu/fragwuerdig/) for you. Please have a look at this and give me a feedback whether this worked for you.

**Edit 2:**

Based on your recent information in the comments I would like you to check the following: Please follow my walkthrough page until step 3. But now, don't type `sudo nemo` but instead type `mount` and hit enter. After that you will see some output which relates to your hard disk devices.

Please post this output. After that I will give you further instructions. You can edit your question "Crashed mint 17.. need to obtain files" to add the outputs of the `mount` command.

Comment: Ok .. info:  i had a stroke and am no longer as smart as I use to be.  When the system crashed I had just done updates.  The page that came up after told me that there were damaged files in my linux mint 17 .. I do not have a linux mint 17 cd.  I have a linux mint 16.  I used that to boot up.  Some how I managed to hit "switch user" .. I am not overly familiar with linux as far as how to access and work around things.   The cd, from the looks of it gave me a secondary user account.  Not sure how to use the cd to boot back into the primary account since "switch user" has been hit.

Comment: Could someone please instruct me exactly how to get my files?  I would appreciate that.  (I don't understand live image.. sorry.)  I have poked around in the file system like I always did with windows and I am seeing absolutely no place "on this user" where it is showing me any files belonging to another user .. that's what is giving me hell.  lol  I don't know how to get back to the other user .. the files are still corrupt I guess on the other user's side .. I know my passwords .. but unsure just how to get back over there to grab the files and then nuke.   Thank you

Comment: Sorry: It is really tricky to help you with such little information. I don't know what you mean by "i somehow managed to hit switch user". When I grab my cinnamon 16 cd plug that into my computer and boot up, then I get right into an cinnamon 16 environment without any "switch user" buttons or dialogs.

Comment: I try to help you anyway: When I boot up using the cinnamon 16 CD, then I can see a 'devices' section on the left bar of the file browser window that I use to poke around in the filesystem. Is that the case for you too: Can you see such section?

Comment: Thank you.. the thing I mean.. I put my 16 CD in .. and it did not automatically run .. I had to tell it boot up with cd.  But you know how when you go to shut down computer .. it says shut down, restart .. so on .. it also says "switch user".  Somehow (probably because of my stupid muscle problems) switch user was hit.  When it booted up, it loaded to it's own new partition.  The part that is bad, is the other part but it does not offer me to go back to that.  I wonder if there is way to see alllllll files.  Even if there is more than one "user account" on computer so I can save files.?.

Comment: Okay, so, when you put your Mint 16 CD into the computer and reboot, did you actually **install** Mint 16 on top of your crashed Mint 17 version???

Comment: Ok .. I used that page and everything you said would come up did .. but it asked for the password for only one account .. both accounts are named the same.. and all that showed up was the files in this account on the computer .. I think I messed up pretty good and the files are just lost.  If I was smart I would just load a new linux and call it a day.  I loaded a copy of mint 17 and it is in iso format.  I can't remember if I can just throw that on a flash drive and boot up the whole system from there or if iso is the wrong format.  I hate having the medical/muscular/memory problem.

Comment: And by the way .. thank you so much for trying to help me and putting the work into doing that walk thru page for me.  :)

Comment: Ah .. and as for the version 16/17 .. when I start the computer it shows me that there are two dif versions .. so I don't understand why the page you showed me didn't work.  When I start the computer it asks briefly if I want to start mint 16.. or 16 in like fix mode .. or if I want to start 17.. or 17 in fix mode.  So the computer thinks the 17 is still there.  So I don't think it did.. and when I did load the 16.. I picked to NOT over write my files because I knew there were things I wanted to keep so it installed along side I think.  But still not letting me see.